# matplotlib: Fliers in boxplot object not setting correctly

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, boxplot

I'm struggling to change the flier markers in boxplots to the custom colors I choose.  After the first three values, it reverts to the defaults.  I see there are a couple of matplotlib issues associated with this, is there any solution to this?

Thanks in advance for the help!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0.15, 0.11, 0.06, 0.06, 0.12, 0.56]
y = [x, x, x, x, x, x]
boxes = plt.boxplot(y, sym="o")

cols = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'orange', 'purple', 'black']

for f, fc in zip(boxes['fliers'], cols):
    f.set_color(fc)
    f.set_markersize(40)
    f.set_alpha(0.6)
    f.set_markeredgecolor("None")
    f.set_marker('.')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Note that [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/boxplot_demo2.html) from the gallery has this issue (the fliers are not red): `plt.setp(bp['fliers'], color='red', marker='+')
` vs. `plt.setp(bp['fliers'], markeredgecolor='red', marker='+')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code as given in the original question does not work in the development release of matplotlib `v1.5dev`. This is because the `set_color` method does not act on the facecolor, instead it should be `set_markerfacecolor`. A complete working example is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = [0.15, 0.11, 0.06, 0.06, 0.12, 0.56]
y = [x, x, x, x, x, x]
boxes = plt.boxplot(y, 
                    flierprops={'alpha':0.6, 
                                'markersize': 40,
                                'markeredgecolor': 'None',
                                'marker': '.'
                                })

cols = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'orange', 'purple', 'black']

for f, fc in zip(boxes['fliers'], cols):
    f.set_markerfacecolor(fc)

plt.show()
```

I have also moved all of the fixed attributes to be set in `flierprops` for readability.

Comment: How / Where can you see the attributes for the fliers (or whatever)?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't think there is documentation relating to this. You can follow the code to find it. To do this, use `ipython`, and run `plt.boxplot??` this gives you the source code and you can search for flierprops and see how it gets used. If you learn a lot, perhaps you could write the docs and submit it to github? Where you looking for something in particular?

Comment: I did look at `plt.boxplot?`, but the most I got there was `flierprops : dict or None (default)
   If provided, will set the plotting style of the fliers`, which is not much :s I was looking for `markerfacecolor` and `markeredgecolor`.

Comment: Glad it could be of use.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working correctly for me, what's your version of matplotlib?

[image]

Comment: Matplotlib 1.3.1.  Mac OSX 10.10.3.  Python 2.7.10, IPython 4.0.0.  Cheers.

Comment: Try installing the latest version: 1.4.3 >>> sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib

Comment: Had another matplotlib folder in the site-packages folder that was 'blocking' the upgrade.  Apologies, seems like a non-question now.  Thanks.